# Non-chromium based browser for Linux apart from Firefox

Tags: linux, web-browser

Chrome and any browser on Chromium engine has a strange nasty bug on my Kubuntu workstation. They randomly crash every 5-10 minutes.

While it would be awesome to fix this, I failed for half a year and kept using Firefox. I have some problems with it too though,so I would like to be aware of alternatives.

Problem is, apart from Firefox, every single modern browser seems to be based on Chromium. OR is there any that is not?

I'm interested in any options that works on Linux and is not Chromium-based, but bonus points if it's modern and actively developed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have issues with any Chromium (Blink) - based Webbrowser, you may try other Firefox(Gecko)-based browsers like **SeaMonkey** or **Waterfox**.

Or use KHTML/Webkit-based browsers:

- **Web** (formerly Epiphany), the default Browser of Gnome.
- **Konqueror**, the default browser from the KDE project.
- **Midori**, the default browser of XFCE.